# Combine 2d xarray dataarray with no common coordinate values

Tags: python-xarray

I have multiple 2d `xarray.DataArray` which do not (necessarily) share common coordinate values. Imagine these DataArray's having come from slicing out multiple (non-overlapping) bounding boxes in a larger gridded dataset.

I'd like to combine the arrays along a new axis `fid` (i.e. a string identifier for the bounding box used to slice each array) without the original 2d coordinates "expanding" and filling with `nan`.

e.g.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# create some toy gridded data
nx = 9
ny = 9
data = np.random.randint(5, size=(nx, ny))
x_coord = np.linspace(0, 1, nx)
y_coord = np.linspace(0, 1, ny)
da = xr.DataArray(
    data,
    dims=("x_coord", "y_coord"),
    coords={"x_coord": x_coord, "y_coord": y_coord}
)

# slice out two subsets of the gridded data
a = da.isel(x_coord=[1, 2, 3], y_coord=[2, 3, 4]).expand_dims(fid=["abc123"])
b = da.isel(x_coord=[6, 7, 8], y_coord=[5, 6, 7]).expand_dims(fid=["def456"])
```

```py
>>> a
<xarray.DataArray (fid: 1, x_coord: 3, y_coord: 3)>
array([[[3, 4, 3],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 4]]])
Coordinates:
  * fid      (fid) object 'abc123'
  * x_coord  (x_coord) float64 0.125 0.25 0.375
  * y_coord  (y_coord) float64 0.25 0.375 0.5

>>> b
<xarray.DataArray (fid: 1, x_coord: 3, y_coord: 3)>
array([[[4, 3, 0],
        [3, 2, 2],
        [4, 2, 1]]])
Coordinates:
  * fid      (fid) object 'def456'
  * x_coord  (x_coord) float64 0.75 0.875 1.0
  * y_coord  (y_coord) float64 0.625 0.75 0.875
```

If I naively try and concatenate these along `fid` dimension, the `x_coord` and `y_coord` expand to encompass all coordinate values from both sources, resulting in a (1, 6, 6) shaped array that is filled with `nan` in most places:

```py
>>> xr.concat([a, b], dim="fid")
<xarray.DataArray (fid: 2, x_coord: 6, y_coord: 6)>
array([[[ 3.,  4.,  3., nan, nan, nan],
        [ 3.,  1.,  0., nan, nan, nan],
        [ 3.,  2.,  4., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  4.,  3.,  0.],
        [nan, nan, nan,  3.,  2.,  2.],
        [nan, nan, nan,  4.,  2.,  1.]]])
Coordinates:
  * fid      (fid) object 'abc123' 'def456'
  * x_coord  (x_coord) float64 0.125 0.25 0.375 0.75 0.875 1.0
  * y_coord  (y_coord) float64 0.25 0.375 0.5 0.625 0.75 0.875
```

I want the resulting array to remain (2, 3, 3) shaped. My idea is to pre-process each individual array to use a "local" coordinates system `(xi, yi)`, e.g.

```py
a_ = a.assign_coords(x_coord=a.x_coord-a.x_coord.min(), y_coord=a.y_coord-a.y_coord.min())
b_ = b.assign_coords(x_coord=b.x_coord-b.x_coord.min(), y_coord=b.y_coord-b.y_coord.min())
>>> xr.concat([a_, b_], dim="fid").rename(x_coord="xi", y_coord="yi")
<xarray.DataArray (fid: 2, xi: 3, yi: 3)>
array([[[3, 4, 3],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 4]],

       [[4, 3, 0],
        [3, 2, 2],
        [4, 2, 1]]])
Coordinates:
  * fid      (fid) object 'abc123' 'def456'
  * xi  (xi) float64 0.0 0.125 0.25
  * yi  (yi) float64 0.0 0.125 0.25
```

... but I also want to keep the "original" coordinate system for each array. I imagine this will involve creating a multidimensional coordinate such that the resulting array has coordinates that go something like:

```py
Coordinates:
  * fid      (fid) object 
                array(['abc123', 'def456'])
  * xi       (xi) float64 
                array([0.0, 0.125, 0.25])
  * yi       (yi) float64 
                array([0.0, 0.125, 0.25])
    x_coord  (fid, xi) float64 
                array([[0.125 0.25 0.375], [0.75 0.875 1.0]])
    y_coord  (fid, yi) float64 
                array([[0.25 0.375 0.5], [0.625 0.75 0.875]])
```

I'm just not quite sure of a neat way to go about doing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! I’d take the same approach in combination with `xr.DataArray.swap_dims`:

```py
a_ = a.assign_coords(
    xi=(a.x_coord - a.x_coord.min()), 
    yi=(a.y_coord - a.y_coord.min()),
).swap_dims({
    "x_coord": "xi",
    "y_coord": "yi",
})

b_ = b.assign_coords(
    xi=(b.x_coord - b.x_coord.min()), 
    yi=(b.y_coord - b.y_coord.min()),
).swap_dims({
    "x_coord": "xi",
    "y_coord": "yi",
})

result = xr.concat([a_, b_], dim="fid")
```

This will preserve the original coordinates while indexing by xi, yi. Note that you will not be able to use the original label values to slice or select, e.g. with `.sel`. Instead, you’ll need to use your new dim labels `(fid, xi, yi)`.

Comment: Glad I’ve now found a use case for swap_dims! Thanks